# Where to download WebSphere Liberty Core IIS plugin?

Tags: iis, websphere-liberty

I am running Liberty Core 16.0.0.4 and would like to use the latest IIS plugin.  I am familiar with the 8.5.5 version that is installed with the WebSphere Customization Toolbox but I was wondering if there was a newer version of that software I should use with the newer version of WLP.

Does anyone know where I can get the latest version of the WAS Plugins for IIS?  Or is there some other method WLP 16.x uses now?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same WAS Plug-in install as traditional WebSphere.

You can either get it from Passport Advantage (Part number: CND1EML) or by pointing your IBM Installation Manager at this repository URL:

V9: http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V9WASSupplements

edit: 8.5.5: http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v85

The part numbers of of the various media included in various WAS products are available in documents like this:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048321

Comment: Thanks for the info!

One question.  You links are for V9 (I have V8.5.x now).  Does this tool exist for V16 or do you know if it will in the future?  I just wanted to make sure I understood...

Comment: It's a bit complicated.  While some _products_ are versioned as 9.0 and 8.5.5, those products share the same Liberty runtime (profile, component, ???).    Those products also include IHS and the WAS plugin at corresponding versions. I added the online repo for 8.5.5 to the answer.